# React-chart does not render the legend for PIE chart

Tags: javascript, reactjs, pie-chart, chart.js

I am using `react-chart` for rendering pie chart in our application. We want to show the legend for the pie chart but can't find any option about how to do that and no help on the `github` repo as well.

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

Found the issue and posting the solution for the same.

Issue - The issue is within the version of react-chart available on `npm`. The latest version available there is `0.6.0` whereas `github` repo have `0.7.3`. The issue is here [react-chart](https://github.com/jhudson8/react-chartjs/blob/master/dist/react-chartjs.js#L106). The snippet in `0.6.0` is as follows

```
classData[name] = function() {
   return this.state.chart[type].apply(this.state.chart, arguments);
};
```

Please see the code which I used to display legend after getting latest version.

`Component File`

```
componentDidUpdate(){
   var pieChartLegend = this.refs.pieChart && this.refs.pieChart.generateLegend();
   if(this.state.chartLegend !== pieChartLegend){this.setState({chartLegend:pieChartLegend});}
}

render(){
   return(
    <div>
    <PieChart ref="pieChart" data={data} style={{height:'60%',width:'100%'}}
    options={
        {
            tooltipTemplate: "<%if (label){%><%=label%>: <%}%><%= value + ' %' %>",
            legendTemplate:"<ul class=\"<%=name.toLowerCase()%>-legend\" style=\"list-style-type: none\"><% for (var i=0; i<segments.length; i++){%><li style=\"text-align: left;\"><span style=\"color:<%=segments[i].fillColor%>\"><%if(segments[i].label){%><%=segments[i].label%><%}%></span></li><%}%></ul>"
        }
    } />
    <div style={{position:'absolute',top:'100px',left:'370px'}} dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: this.state.chartLegend}} />
    </div>
    )
}
```